# Syntax error in OpenGl shader that is copied from YouTube

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader, glew

I trying to learn OpenGl and now I wanted to make a simple red triangle on a black background with vertices and shaders. I copied the code [from that YouTube video.](https://youtu.be/71BLZwRGUJE) I've changed a view things. That's my code:

```
#include "prec.h"
struct Vector2
{
    float x, y;
};

struct TrianglePos
{
    Vector2 a, b, c;
};

static unsigned int CompileShader(unsigned int type, const std::string& source)
{
    unsigned int id = glCreateShader(type);
    const char* src = source.c_str();
    glShaderSource(id, 1, &src, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(id);

    int result;
    glGetShaderiv(id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result);
    if (!result)
    {
        int length;
        glGetShaderiv(id, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &length);
        char* message = (char*)alloca(length * sizeof(char));
        glGetShaderInfoLog(id, length, &length, message);
        std::cout << "Failed to compile shader, message: " << message << std::endl;
        glDeleteShader(id);
        return 0;
    }

    return id;
}

static unsigned int createShader(const std::string& vertexShader, const std::string& fragmentShader)
{
    unsigned int program = glCreateProgram();
    unsigned int vs = CompileShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShader);
    unsigned int fs = CompileShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShader);

    glAttachShader(program, vs);
    glAttachShader(program, fs);
    glLinkProgram(program);
    glValidateProgram(program);

    glDeleteShader(vs);
    glDeleteShader(fs);

    return program;
}

int main() {

    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;


    GLFWwindow *window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Sand Box GL", NULL, NULL);

    if (!window) {
        std::cout << "problems with window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    if (GLEW_OK != glewInit()) {
        std::cout << "something with glew went wrong" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }


    TrianglePos trianglePos = {
            -0.5f, -0.5f,
            0.0f, 0.5f,
            0.5f, -0.5f
    };

    unsigned int buffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(trianglePos), &trianglePos, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vector2), 0);

    std::string vertexShader =
            "#version 400 core\n"
            "\n"
            "layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;\n"
            "\n"
            "void main() \n"
            "{\n"
            "   gl_Position = position;\n"
            "}\n";

    std::string fragmentShader =
            "#version 400 core\n"
            "\n"
            "layout(location = 0) out vec4 color;\n"
            "\n"
            "void main()\n"
            "{\n"
            "   color = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);\n"
            "}\n";

    const char *versionGL;
    versionGL = (char *) (glGetString(GL_VERSION));
    std::cout << "openGl version: " << versionGL << std::endl;

    if(GL_VERSION_4_0)
        std::cout << "opengl 4.0 supported" << std::endl;

    unsigned int shader = createShader(vertexShader, fragmentShader);
    glUseProgram(shader);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

and that's the precompiled header (prec.h): #pragma once

```
#ifndef GLEWINIT_PREC_H
#define GLEWINIT_PREC_H
#endif //GLEWINIT_PREC_H

#include "GL/glew.h"
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <iostream>
```

the program prints that to the console ("OpenGL 4.0 supported" means that `GL_VERSION_4_0 == true`):

```
openGl version: 2.1 INTEL-14.5.22 
opengl 4.0 supported
```

When I try to run it I get this error message from the shader Compiler for my vertex and fragment shader:

```
ERROR: 0:1: '' :  version '400' is not supported
ERROR: 0:1: '' : syntax error: #version
ERROR: 0:3: 'layout' : syntax error: syntax error
```

When I change the `#version 400 core` to `#version 120` I only get the syntax error for the `layout`. Because of that I think I messed up something with glew. What could I try?

Comment: I don't use GLEW, but my bet is that `GL_VERSION_4_0` is a compile time define that tells what version GLEW is going to try to load. It says nothing about what OpenGL version is actually supported on your hardware. So probably OpenGL 2.1 is best your hardware supports.

Comment: And what could I do because of the syntax error?

Comment: Do it the old way, without the `layout` qualifier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your system does not support OpenGL 4.0. It just supports OpenGL 2.1. See the output

> ```
> openGl version: 2.1 INTEL-14.5.22
> ```

[GLSL 1.20](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.1.20.pdf) corresponds to  OpenGL 2.1. Downgrade the shader:

Vertex shader

```c
#version 120

attribute vec4 position;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = position;
}
```

Fragment shader

```c
#version 120

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Respectively using [Raw string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) ([C++11](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/11)):

```cpp
std::string vertexShader =
R"(#version 120

attribute vec4 position;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = position;
}
)";

std::string fragmentShader =
R"(#version 120

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
)";
```

Comment: For me the raw string doesn't work. But with the normal string it's working thank you very much Rabbid76!

Comment: @GianLaager Thank you. You're welcome. Raw string literals are  supported since [C++11](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/11)